# Why does my program end after the last scanf?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, scanf, ampersand

I am writing a program with structs and pointers. As you will see in the program I am asking the user if he wants to continue adding students. And I want to check if his answer is `Yes` or `No`. Obviously I am doing something wrong because my program finishes after his answer. So I want help to spot the bug and to find a way to write the code correctly.

Also I want to ask why `number[i].age` needs an `&` in font of it in `scanf`. I mean it is a pointer so why use a `&`?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef struct student {

  char name[30];
  int age;

}student ;

int main(){
 typedef int size;
 int i;
 size siz=0;
 student *number;

   printf("Welcome\n\nEnter the number of student you want to evaluate: ");
   scanf("%d",&siz);

   printf("\n");


   number=malloc(siz*(sizeof(struct student)));


   for(i=0;i<siz;i++){

                      printf("Student name: ");
                      scanf("%s",number[i].name);

                      printf("Student age: ");
                      scanf("%d",&number[i].age);
                      printf("\n");
    }

      printf("Do you want to add Students(Yes or No)? ");

      void * answer;
      scanf("%s",*answer);
      
   if(strcmp(answer, "Yes")==0){

        printf("\n Give the number of the additional students: ");

        int adsize;

        scanf("%d",&adsize);

  student*realloc=(number,adsize*sizeof(int));
  int j=0;
  for(j=0;j<adsize;j++){
                           printf("Student name: ");
                           scanf("%c",number[j].name);

                           printf("Student age: ");
                           scanf("%d",number[j].age);
                           printf("\n");
  }
}
else
    printf("\nEnd of programm");





return 0;

}
```

Comment: The compiler should complain about `strcmp(answer[40], "Yes")`. The first argument is a single `char` element, not a string. And an element that is out of bounds.

Comment: And `number[i].age` is *not* a pointer. That's why you need the pointer-to operator `&`, to get a pointer to it.

Comment: Oh and `realloc=(number,adsize)`? Doesn't the compiler complain about that either? Either way, it's wrong anyway even after you remove the extra `=`, because the size you should pass is the size in bytes. Just as for `malloc`. I recommend you enable more warnings from the compiler, and treat any and all warnings as *errors* that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to "fix" the code. That makes it no longer have the problem you ask about, and the question becomes kind of useless. Add a comment saying what the problem was, or post an answer yourself, or just delete it if you feel it was such a simple problem that it didn't need a proper answer.

Comment: Actually, your edit kind of makes the coded even worse! It was good before, except that you passed the wrong thing to `strcmp`. Now you try to dereference an uninitialized `void *` pointer for some reason. Why? Why did you make that change?

Comment: Judging by the original code and your new code, you seem to have some very basic misunderstandings about C. Please take some time to refresh your beginners learning resources about how to use strings and pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You must learn to indent the code properly for you and others to gain readability.

Here is a reformatted version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct student {
    char name[30];
    int age;
} student;

int main() {
    typedef int size;
    int i;
    size siz = 0;
    student *number;

    printf("Welcome\n\nEnter the number of student you want to evaluate: ");
    scanf("%d", &siz);

    printf("\n");

    number = malloc(siz * (sizeof(struct student)));

    for (i = 0; i < siz; i++) {
        printf("Student name: ");
        scanf("%s", number[i].name);

        printf("Student age: ");
        scanf("%d", &number[i].age);
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Do you want to add Students(Yes or No)? ");

    void *answer;
    scanf("%s", *answer);

    if (strcmp(answer, "Yes") == 0) {

        printf("\n Give the number of the additional students: ");

        int adsize;
        scanf("%d", &adsize);

        student *realloc = (number, adsize * sizeof(int));
        int j = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < adsize; j++) {
            printf("Student name: ");
            scanf("%c", number[j].name);

            printf("Student age: ");
            scanf("%d", number[j].age);
            printf("\n");
        }
    } else
        printf("\nEnd of programm");

    return 0;
}
```

Some problems appear immediately:

- `typedef int size;` defines a type with a local scope in the function `main`.  Avoid this type of definition that is confusing and error prone.
- in `scanf("%d", &siz)`, you do not test the return value of `scanf()`.  This is risky as invalid or missing input will be ignored and cause unexpected behavior if not undefined behavior later in the code.  **Always** test for and report invalid or missing input:

  ```
    if (scanf("%d", &siz) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid or missing input\n");
        exit(1);
    }
  ```
- you allocate memory with `malloc` but do not check for allocation failure.  testing for and reporting memory allocation failure will help track problems too.
- `scanf("%s", number[i].name);` does not need the `&` because `number[i].name` is an array and arrays are always passed as a pointer to their first element.  Yet this `scanf()` call is risky because you do not provide `scanf()` with a way to prevent buffer overflow on overlong input. Use this instead:

  ```
    if (scanf("%29s", number[i].name) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid or missing input for number[%d].name\n", i);
        exit(1);
    }
  ```
- `scanf("%d", &number[i].age);` needs the `&` because `number[i].age` is an `int` member and you must pass its address to `scanf` for it to store the converted value.  Of course you must test the return value to detect and report invalid or missing input.
- `void *answer; scanf("%s", *answer);` is completely bogus: you dereference a `void` pointer, which would not compile in Standard C (your compiler might support it an extension) and `answer` is uninitialized anyway, so dereferencing the pointer has undefined behavior, probably a segmentation fault, which causes your program to stop as observed.  You should write this instead:

  ```
    char answer[10];
    if (scanf("%9s", answer) != 1 || strcmp(answer, "Yes")) {
        printf("end of program\n");
        return 0;
    }
  ```
- `student*realloc=(number,adsize*sizeof(int));` is the most surprising! it is actually parsed as

  ```
    student *realloc = (number, adsize * sizeof(int));
  ```

  which defines a local variable `realloc` as a pointer to `student`, initialized with the conversion of `adsize * sizeof(int)` as a pointer... quite meaningless and no side effect on the array pointed to by `number`.
- in the second loop, `scanf("%c", number[j].name)` uses the wrong conversion specifier `%c` which reads a single character into a `char` variable, not a string into an array of `char`.  Only the first character will be read (most likely a pending newline) and stored into the first entry of the `name` array, leaving the rest uninitialized, ie: not even forming a proper string.  Use `scanf("%29s", number[j].name)` instead and check the return value.

You should definitely compile with extra warnings to detect such errors using **gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror** or similar options for your compiler.

Here is a modified version for you to study:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct student {
    char name[30];
    int age;
} student;

int main(void) {
    printf("Welcome\n\n"
           "Enter the number of students you want to evaluate: ");

    int size;
    if (scanf("%d", &size) != 1 || size <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid or missing size\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\n");

    student *number = malloc(sizeof(struct student) * size);
    if (number == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory for %d students\n", size);
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("Student name: ");
        if (scanf("%29s", number[i].name) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid or missing name\n");
            return 1;
        }

        printf("Student age: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &number[i].age) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid or missing age\n");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Do you want to add Students(Yes or No)? ");

    char answer[10];
    if (scanf("%9s", answer) == 1 && strcmp(answer, "Yes") == 0) {

        printf("\nGive the number of the additional students: ");

        int adsize;
        if (scanf("%d", &adsize) != 1 || adsize <= 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid or missing size\n");
            return 1;
        }

        student *new_number = realloc(number, sizeof(student) * (size + adsize));
        if (new_number == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot reallocate memory for %d extra students\n", adsize);
            return 1;
        }
        number = new_number;
        for (int i = size; i < size + adsize; i++) {
            printf("Student name: ");
            if (scanf("%29s", number[i].name) != 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "invalid or missing name\n");
                return 1;
            }

            printf("Student age: ");
            if (scanf("%d", &number[i].age) != 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "invalid or missing age\n");
                return 1;
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        size += adsize;
    }
    printf("Students:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("    %s, %d\n", number[i].name, number[i].age);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("End of program\n");

    free(number);
    return 0;
}
```